# jquery in select (views module) -- change submit click to link

Tags: views, javascript

This is regular Views selector exposed to user:

---

[image: This is regular Views selector exposed to user]

---

This is a part of block, attached to Panel on main page. I want to create links "show expiring" and "show latest" but I need to learn what function is fired while clicking Apply. Anyone knows where can I find it? Debugging it with Chrome is tricky, a lot of JS files…

Is there a way of previewing all javascript acitvity?

Comment: modules/views/js/ajax_view.js - maybe somewhere there… I keep investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image above shows an exposed form generated by Views in the file `views_plugin_exposed_form.inc.`  Line 242 in the function `exposed_form_alter` reads       `$form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'ctools') . '/js/auto-submit.js';` so the js looks to be in ctools however, I believe that script is being called whenever a change is made on the form.  If you want to modify the form note that views is managing the form in this file. Selecting the 'Apply' button calls `exposed_form_validate` and `exposed_form_submit` which are tapping into the Drupal form API (php not JS). Go to api.drupal.org to find out more about the various hooks available to modify the forms